# Using ExtWebComponents how could I create a simple view?

Tags: extjs, web-component, extwebcomponents

I would like to composite several components and elements together, how could I do that using Sencha ExtWebComponents?

For example:

```
<div>View</div>
<ext-button></ext-button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's is a simple example of how you could composite web components.

**Consuming the component:**

1. In the index.js, I have imported the button component and imported the component with `import './SandboxViewComponent';`
2. In the index.html, I'm declaring my with `<my-sandbox-view></my-sandboxy-view>`.

**Source Below**

SandboxViewComponent.js

```
import template from './SandboxViewComponent.html';

class SandboxViewComponent extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super()

    this.innerHTML = template;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    var me = this;

    // Add after the buttonEl.ext.el is instantiated
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        me._addListeners();
      }, 0);
    }, 0);
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
  }

  _addListeners() {
    var buttonEl = this.querySelector("ext-button");

    button.ext.on("tap", function () {
        alert("tap 1 works");
    });

    button.ext.addListener("tap", function() {
        alert("tap 2 works");
    });

    buttonEl.ext.el.on('click', () => {
      alert('ext on click works');
    });
  }

}
window.customElements.define('my-sandbox-view', SandboxViewComponent);
```

SandboxViewComponent.html

```
<div>Sandbox View</div>

<ext-button
        text="Button 1"
        shadow="true"
        arrowAlign="bottom"
        ></ext-button>
```

- https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/38097b0fb4e6a1c5a773edf2cf532843 - Source here too
- Sencha will be fixing the Sencha fiddle so this example will run there soon.